# Cisco NAT from Outside Interface to Outside Interface

Tags: cisco, nat

Is it possible to create a NAT rule that translates [changing the source IP] traffic coming from a NAT OUTSIDE interface and that goes to the Internet via another NAT OUTSIDE interface?

[image: MAP]

I just want to know if it is possible to create a NAT rule that allows one of our Service Provider segment [192.166.5.0/24] to access the Internet without changing the NAT interface type [from NAT OUTSIDE to NAT INSIDE] there are some other configurations that make difficult for me to make that change [There are two NAT rules that are being used as virtual IPs to give access to a SFTP server], I want hosts [192.168.5.15 and 192.168.15.16] to access the Internet.

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance

PD: Sorry for the previous post, the map looked well on the editor but it looked horrible in the post. I'm attaching a network map image

Comment: Your post is a bit confusing. Try to clean it up and provide a better diagram. I'm not sure what you are asking. Do you want to do both PAT and static NAT?

Comment: Please consider adding a better diagram and the router config

Comment: I've just edited my post, hopefully it is more clear now, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer**: Assuming this is Cisco - no you can't NAT between two OUTSIDE interfaces*

**Corollary**: you can achieve what you want by migrating your NAT configuration to use NAT Virtual Interface (NVI). NVI precludes the need to have INSIDE/OUTSIDE interfaces and is the *new* way to do things. I think you will need at least 12.3T (possibly 12.4T will have to check).

*You can do what you are trying to do with the addition of a route-map and a loopback address but I'm not going to suggest or recommend it.

Comment: Yes it is Cisco, actually the configuration is using two ISR 1941 configured in Failover with HSRP running IOS 15.3(2)T. Thanks for the answer.